# wxPython: How the radio buttons can remember my choice when I close the frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

Hello I have one main frame and a button which when its pressed a second frame opens. The second frame have 6 radio buttons. My question is when I choose a radiobutton different from the allready selected and close the frame and when I open it again (without close the entire program) why is selected the first one and how can I keep my new selection?

Here is some part of the seconds frame code:

```
    self.radio1 = wx.RadioButton(self, label="1 sec",pos=(35,35),)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.SetLab1, id=self.radio1.GetId())

    self.radio2 = wx.RadioButton(self, label="2 sec",pos=(35,55))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.SetLab2, id=self.radio2.GetId())

    self.radio3 = wx.RadioButton(self, label="4 sec",pos=(35,75))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.SetLab3, id=self.radio3.GetId())
                                  .
                                  .
                                  .

    self.button0=AB.AquaButton(self,label="Exit",pos=(115,142),size=(90,35))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton0, self.button0)

def OnButton0(self, event):
    self.Close()

def SetLab1(self,event):
    global Delay
    Delay = 'A2/'

def SetLab2(self,event):
    global Delay
    Delay = 'A3/'

def SetLab3(self,event):
    global Delay
    Delay = 'A4/'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you close the frame you destroy it and when you build it again it will go back to its default state.

you can do something like:

```
self.radio1 = wx.RadioButton(self, label="1 sec",pos=(35,35),)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.SetLab1, id=self.radio1.GetId())

self.radio2 = wx.RadioButton(self, label="2 sec",pos=(35,55))
self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.SetLab2, id=self.radio2.GetId())

self.radio3 = wx.RadioButton(self, label="4 sec",pos=(35,75))
self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.SetLab3, id=self.radio3.GetId())
global Delay
if Delay is not None:
     getattr(self,"radio"+str(int(Delay[1])-1)).SetValue(True)
```

that will select the radio button that matches the value in the global Delay variable.

An easier solution is not to "Close" the frame but rather to hide it

```
#instead of my_frame.Close() (or my_frame.Destroy())
my_frame.Hide()
```

this keeps the constructed frame so when you next show it it will still have all its values

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tried the second example but it didn't work, and for the first one how I supposed to do?

Comment: well I cant see how you are closing the frame in your example so its hard for me to tell you how that works .... edited to be more explicit on how to select one of the radio buttons