# wxPython: How the CheckBox can remember my choice when I close the frame

Tags: checkbox, wxpython

I have two frames the second frame have some checkboxes. How can I keep my selections when I close the second frame?

Here is an example code!

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test",size=(300,200))

        self.Btn = wx.Button(self, label="New",pos=(10,10),size=(30,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.new, self.Btn)

    def new(self, event):
        newFrame().Show()

class newFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test 2",size=(300,200))

        self.ch0 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1,"Choice 1",pos=(10,10))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.OnCB0, self.ch0)
        self.ch1 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1,"Choise 2",pos=(10,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.OnCB1, self.ch1)
        self.ch2 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1,"Choise 3",pos=(10,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.OnCB2, self.ch2)

    def OnCB0(self, event):
        if self.ch0.IsChecked():
            print "Checked 1"
        else:
            print "UnChecked 1"

    def OnCB1(self, event):
        if self.ch1.IsChecked():
            print "Checked 2"
        else:
            print "UnChecked 2"

    def OnCB2(self, event):
        if self.ch2.IsChecked():
            print "Checked 3"
        else:
            print "UnChecked 3"      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    app.frame = MainFrame()
    app.frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I had made a similar post here:

[wxPython: How the radio buttons can remember my choice when I close the frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960314/wxpython-how-the-radio-buttons-can-remember-my-choise-when-i-close-the-frame)

But it didn't work.

**####EDIT####**

I have made some changes but still it doesn't work as I want. Now when I open again the second frame it holds only one choice, the last that I checked. How can I make it hold more than one choices?

```
import wx

hold = None

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test",size=(300,200))

        self.Btn = wx.Button(self, label="New",pos=(10,10),size=(30,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.new, self.Btn)

    def new(self, event):
        newFrame().Show()

class newFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test 2",size=(300,200))

        self.ch0 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1,"Choice 1",pos=(10,10))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.OnCB0, id=self.ch0.GetId())
        self.ch1 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1,"Choise 2",pos=(10,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.OnCB1, id=self.ch1.GetId())
        self.ch2 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1,"Choise 3",pos=(10,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.OnCB2, id=self.ch2.GetId())

        global hold
        if hold is not None:
            getattr(self,"ch"+str(int(hold[1])-1)).SetValue(True)

    def OnCB0(self, event):
        global hold
        hold = 'd1/'
        if self.ch0.IsChecked():
            print "Checked 1"
        else:
            print "UnChecked 1"

    def OnCB1(self, event):
        global hold
        hold = 'd2/'
        if self.ch1.IsChecked():
            print "Checked 2"
        else:
            print "UnChecked 2"

    def OnCB2(self, event):
        global hold
        hold = 'd3/'
        if self.ch2.IsChecked():
            print "Checked 3"
        else:
            print "UnChecked 3"      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    app.frame = MainFrame()
    app.frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it didn't work"?

Comment: I think you need to share some code that shows how you are "closing the second frame".  In the other question you posted, the recommendation was to not close it, but rather to hide it.   Are you doing that here?

Comment: tom10:I tried to do the same in this code but I had errors.
 

GreenAsJade: I am not try to hide the frame as mentioned in the other question I tried the second suggestion in Joran Beasley's answer.

Comment: How is it going? Does the answer help?

Comment: IMHO, the second way of doing it, represented by your edit, is a bad way.  There might be reasons for doing it this way, but it is something to avoid in general.  The method in my first answer appears more attractive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joran described in the question you pointed to, you need to *not* destroy the new frame and recreate it each time.   Then it will be able to remember what was checked.   Note that clicking on the window manager "close" button (the 'x') *destroys* the frame, by default.

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test",size=(300,200))

        self.Btn = wx.Button(self, label="New",pos=(10,10),size=(30,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.show_newFrame, self.Btn)

        # create the newFrame instance, keep it around.
        self.new_frame = newFrame()

    def show_newFrame(self, event):
        self.new_frame.Show()

class newFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test 2",size=(300,200))

        self.ch0 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1,"Choice 1",pos=(10,10))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.OnCB0, self.ch0)
        self.ch1 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1,"Choise 2",pos=(10,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.OnCB1, self.ch1)
        self.ch2 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1,"Choise 3",pos=(10,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.OnCB2, self.ch2)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onClose)

    # hide ourself on close, don't destroy
    def onClose(self, event):
        self.Hide()


    def OnCB0(self, event):
        if self.ch0.IsChecked():
            print "Checked 1"
        else:
            print "UnChecked 1"

    def OnCB1(self, event):
        if self.ch1.IsChecked():
            print "Checked 2"
        else:
            print "UnChecked 2"

    def OnCB2(self, event):
        if self.ch2.IsChecked():
            print "Checked 3"
        else:
            print "UnChecked 3"      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    app.frame = MainFrame()
    app.frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your second version doesn't work is because you are using only one variable to try to save the state of three checkboxes.

Clearly, the variable called "hold" can only contain one checkbox name to hold - the way your code works, it saves the name of the last checkbox that was pressed.

If you insist on doing it this way, you will have to do something like this:

```
import wx

hold = [None, None, None]

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test",size=(300,200))

        self.Btn = wx.Button(self, label="New",pos=(10,10),size=(30,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.new, self.Btn)

    def new(self, event):
        newFrame().Show()

class newFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test 2",size=(300,200))

        self.ch0 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1,"Choice 1",pos=(10,10))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.OnCB0, id=self.ch0.GetId())
        self.ch1 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1,"Choise 2",pos=(10,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.OnCB1, id=self.ch1.GetId())
        self.ch2 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1,"Choise 3",pos=(10,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.OnCB2, id=self.ch2.GetId())

        global hold
        for hold_item in hold:
            if hold_item:
                getattr(self,"ch"+str(int(hold_item[1])-1)).SetValue(True)

    def OnCB0(self, event):
        global hold
        if self.ch0.IsChecked():
            print "Checked 1"
            hold[0] = 'd1/'
        else:
            print "UnChecked 1"
            hold[0] = None

    def OnCB1(self, event):
        global hold
        if self.ch1.IsChecked():
            print "Checked 2"
            hold[1] = 'd2/'
        else:
            print "UnChecked 2"
            hold[1] = None

    def OnCB2(self, event):
        global hold
        if self.ch2.IsChecked():
            print "Checked 3"
            hold[2] = 'd3/'
        else:
            print "UnChecked 3"      
            hold[2] = None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    app.frame = MainFrame()
    app.frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

However, this is undesirable because:

1. You create the second frame from scratch every time, which is
   expensive
2. It uses global variables which are ugly